# Chrome Device Mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome now has a very helpful "device mode" that can be used to preview a web page as it might appear on a host of devices.  Very useful.  I was wondering...  is there a way to enter/exit device mode via JS run from the page itself.  For some of what I do it would be handy to let people preview screens on different devices without having to explain that they can do this via the button on Chrome Developer tools.  Googling has not yielded any obvious ways to accomplish this - perhaps  it is not possble?ch