# How to force Chrome Device Mode?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-development

Can I open a new Chrome window with Device Mode automatically enabled, either via the JS launching the new window, or some code on the destination page?

Comment: this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258503/chrome-device-mode sorry!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding based on Paul Bakaus' video at the Chrome Dev Summit 2015 is that Device Mode will be the default in Chrome Dev Tools from Chrome 48 or 49 - https://youtu.be/dJR-n8szgBc?list=PLNYkxOF6rcICcHeQY02XLvoGL34rZFWZn&t=679